# Need help rewriting a Python function without using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, callback

Basically I just want to know what this piece of code will look like if the lambda wasn't used.

```
bttn_0 = Button(calc, text = "0")

bttn_0["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(0)

bttn_0.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 5)
```

I know it will start of as def something but I'm pretty lost in terms of what will go where. You may wonder WHY I'm asking this. Well I'm trying to figure out the use of lambda and how to use it more efficiently in my coding but I first need to know how to implement it from a original def function without lambda. I hope this makes sense. I am aware that lambda is the quickest method but as I said, I'm still interested in learning about simplifying my coding and will need the original way to do it before I can get fancy.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `def somename(): return sum1.num_press(0)` and then `bttn_0["command"] = somename`. This is covered in many tutorials, please do some research next time...

Comment: using lambda in this situation isn't "fancy", it's the normal way to create a callback that must pass in an arbitrary value. To do it any other way would be to over-engineer the solution.

Comment: @14mpi There's no need for you to waste your time by commenting that. I asked a question. Deal with it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only meaningful other option is passing a named function:

```
def command_handler():
    return sum1.num_press(0)  # or without the return

bttn_0["command"] = command_handler
```

but there is no difference there, and the lambda looks much better in my opinion (although some people prefer to avoid them for whatever reasons of style or taste) — you need to pass a callable, and the only way to define a callable is a lambda or a function.

A third option, technically speaking, is an object with a `__call__` method but that's by far an overkill here, so I'm only demonstrating it for completeness' sake:

```
class CmdHandler(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return sum1.num_press(0)

bttn_0["command"] = CmdHandler()
```

Comment: "or without the return"?

Comment: If the return value is not used by whatever is calling the handler (the button instance), you can get rid of the `return`, but since the expression in a lambda is always returned from that lambda, I kept it semantically identical by including the `return`.

Comment: Alternatively: `functools.partial(sum1.num_press, 0)`

Comment: ...which is just a longer version of `lambda: sum1.num_press(0)` basically (which also requires an extra import), but yeah, that's an option, and, again, some people prefer it for reasons I tend to disagree with.

Comment: @ErikAllik Actually, it's not just a longer version. The partial object includes the function that `sum1.num_press` is bound to at the time of the call to `partial`; a `lambda` defers the lookup until the function is actually called, by which time (in theory) the binding could have changed. It's also more efficient, since the lookup is done once and cached.

Comment: 1) efficiency is offtopic in the majority of cases and I think the difference here is miniscule anyway, and 2) it's not too typical for it to be desirable that the lookup be immediate... and you can also achieve that with a lambda anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much. But one question, where does the button grid part go? "bttn_0.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 5) " I understand the rest very well thank you.

Comment: what do you mean where? what's wrong with it where it is?

Comment: Okay let me explain. The code you provided does not include the "bttn_0.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 5) " part. I don't see reference to that part anywhere in your coding. Now my question is where does it go? I don't see you the mention of the row or column anywhere in the def function. Does it go below the code? Please help. This is why I asked this question in the first place to get help with the entire block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two examples:

Without the lambda expression, if you wanted to print numbers (for example), you'd need a different function for each Button:

```
def number_0():
    print 0

def number_1():
    print 1

Button(calc, text='0 named function', command=number_0).pack()
Button(calc, text='1 named function', command=number_1).pack()
```

However, with the lambda expression, you can pass an argument from the Button, and you can greatly reduce the number of lines in your code:

```
def num_press(n):
    print n

Button(calc, text='0 with lambda', command=lambda: num_press(0)).pack()
Button(calc, text='1 with lambda', command=lambda: num_press(1)).pack()
```

Comment: Just commented on the other answer too. Where does the bttn_0.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 5) part go? Or is that not included somewhere else and not in the function for each button. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what I'm looking for. Can you just explain where it goes or not?

Comment: `.grid` is a geometry manager for Tkinter. It places a widget in a location on the GUI. You should go through the introduction and look up some tutorials to understand how to use it, because you won't get very far without learning how to use this simple method yourself.

Comment: It's OK, I figured it out. Thanks for the help.